# PHP client acknowledge (BattlEye)

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, protocols

https://www.battleye.com/downloads/BERConProtocol.txt

The following code is a remote connection to a game server via. (RCon) BattlEye protocol (link above). Basically it's just reading and write on the socket.

The script sends the command **say -1 TEST** to the server.

As you can see it's an inifite loop.

After sleeping for 1s the cmd should be sent and the loop begins again.

```
$pass =        "my_rcon_pw";
$ip =          "12.34.56.78";
$port =        2309;

//

$authCRC = sprintf('%x', crc32(chr(255).chr(00).trim($pass)));
$authCRC = array(substr($authCRC,-2,2), substr($authCRC,-4,2), substr($authCRC,-6,2), substr($authCRC,0,2));

$loginMsg = 'BE'.chr(hexdec($authCRC[0])).chr(hexdec($authCRC[1])).chr(hexdec($authCRC[2])).chr(hexdec($authCRC[3]));
$loginMsg .= chr(hexdec('ff')).chr(hexdec('00')).trim($pass);

$hbMsg = 'BE'.chr(hexdec('7d')).chr(hexdec('8f')).chr(hexdec('ef')).chr(hexdec('73'));
$hbMsg .= chr(hexdec('ff')).chr(hexdec('02')).chr(hexdec('00'));

//

$server = @fsockopen( "udp://" . $ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1 );

if( $server === false ) throw new \Exception( 'Could not bind to socket: ' . $errstr );

//

$sent = fwrite( $server, $loginMsg );

if( $sent === false ) throw new \Exception( 'Failed to send login!' );

$result = fread( $server, 16 );

if( @ord( $result[strlen( $result ) - 1] ) == 0 ) throw new \Exception( 'Login failed, wrong password or wrong port!' );

//

for(;;)
{
    sleep(1);

    $command =    "say -1 TEST";

    $msgCRC = sprintf('%x', crc32(chr(255).chr(01).chr(hexdec(sprintf('%01b', 0))).trim($command)));
    $msgCRC = array(substr($msgCRC,-2,2),substr($msgCRC,-4,2),substr($msgCRC,-6,2),substr($msgCRC,0,2));

    $cmdHead = 'BE'.chr(hexdec($msgCRC[0])).chr(hexdec($msgCRC[1])).chr(hexdec($msgCRC[2])).chr(hexdec($msgCRC[3])).chr(hexdec('ff')).chr(hexdec('01')).chr(hexdec(sprintf('%01b', 0)));
    $cmdMsg = $cmdHead.trim($command);

    //

    $cmd = fwrite( $server, $cmdMsg );

    if( $cmd === false ) throw new \Exception( 'Failed to send command!' );
}
```

After 9-10 s the connection of the client is getting closed by the server. This happens because the client needs to send a verification to the servers he's still alive.

The following code adds a "heartbeat" ca. every 10 s to the loop.

```
for(;;)
{
    if( !isset( $i ) ) $i = 0;

    sleep(1);

    $command =    "say -1 TEST";

    $msgCRC = sprintf('%x', crc32(chr(255).chr(01).chr(hexdec(sprintf('%01b', 0))).trim($command)));
    $msgCRC = array(substr($msgCRC,-2,2),substr($msgCRC,-4,2),substr($msgCRC,-6,2),substr($msgCRC,0,2));

    $cmdHead = 'BE'.chr(hexdec($msgCRC[0])).chr(hexdec($msgCRC[1])).chr(hexdec($msgCRC[2])).chr(hexdec($msgCRC[3])).chr(hexdec('ff')).chr(hexdec('01')).chr(hexdec(sprintf('%01b', 0)));
    $cmdMsg = $cmdHead.trim($command);

    //

    $cmd = fwrite( $server, $cmdMsg );

    if( $cmd === false ) throw new \Exception( 'Failed to send command!' );

    $i++;

    //

    if( $i == 9 )
    {
        $hb = fwrite( $server, $hbMsg );

        if( $hb === false ) throw new \Exception( 'Failed to send heartbeat!' );

        unset( $i );
    }
}
```

Curiously this heartbeat works only **once a time**.
This means the client is timing out not ~ 10 s after begin, no now it's around 20 s after begin.

And that's the whole issue on this code.

I'm running it in PHP console - so there's no max executing time or anything else.

The goal is to run this as "persistent" connection between client and server.

---

**The issue**

Like the protocol says the client needs to acknowledge packets of the server or will time out.

How can I acknowledge incoming packets like described in the protocol?

And is there maybe something wrong with my heartbeat packet to the server?

---

I would really appreciate any kind of tip or help :)

Thanks so far and German greetings!